# How are unknown objects or elements defined in UML?

Tags: uml

If I have an unknown group of elements e.g. person, servers, etc is there a way to classify these in UML?

For example, how do you classify a server that has no name as this information was lost and there is no documentation or other information about it? Does UML have recognizable placeholder names?

Comment: What kind of diagram are you drawing?

Comment: @flup - Class, Deployment and Use Case in most instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous instances of a class are denoted as :̲c̲l̲a̲s̲s̲ in UML.

[image]

Would that suit you?